# Why does my .bat file abruptly end after calling another .bat file?

Tags: batch-file, cmd

Relatively simple thing here without a readily discoverable answer...I've tried variations of start, /K flags, etc etc, but whenever my batch file hits the `servicecontroller` line and runs that command it completes the command but doesn't do anything after. Please advise.

```
cd c:\blackboard\tools\admin
servicecontroller.bat services.stop
echo ! ! ! Blackboard services have successfully stopped. It is now safe to shut down the computer or database server. ! ! !
timeout /15
```

Comment: Use `CALL servicecontroller.bat services.stop`

Answer (score 8):

batch files have no memory where any particular line came from. If you execute another batch file from within a batch file, the original file is essentially "gone".

foo.bat:

```
echo in foo
bar.bat
echo called bat  <--never called
```

bar.bat:

```
echo in bar
```

baz.bat:

```
echo in baz
call bar.bat
echo back in baz   <--will be called
```

Note the `call` in `baz.bat`. It's vaguely/kinda/sorta the difference between `goto` and `gosub`. goto unconditionally transfers control to the new location, while "gosub" allows for a "return" to the original calling context.

Comment: I also tried call before creating this question, it still doesn't work. Any other ideas?

Comment: check what's happening inside that blackboard .bat file. it could be killing the batch process, instead of allowing a normal "run off the end" termination.

Comment: Yeah I just did, the last command is a popd command. Annoying. Typical blackboard.

Comment: I usually use `CALL` before every .bat command, but in this case I was calling a series of .bat files from an Electron main and couldn't get beyond the first one. If I would manually end one, the next would come up - taking out the `CALL` from the .bat command fixed that for me - Thanks !

Answer (score 0):

i had the exit command mentioned on the script being called. it will not return to the calling script after completion but will exit of command line.
I removed the exit command and it is now returning control to the calling script